# Bizarre Love Triangle

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

I work in quite an unusual office. Everybody who works here has a colour for their surname! It’s a bit like that old board game Cluedo, except nobody has been murdered. Still, there is a bit of a mystery to be solved around here. There’s been a lot of gossip around the water cooler about a “love triangle” in the office. Apparently one of my colleagues really likes somebody in the office, but sadly the object of their affections likes somebody else instead!

One of my workmates reckoned they figured it all out, yet wouldn’t tell me anything. But when I was at the office shredder last night I found what was left of their notes. It didn’t take me long to piece it back together.

[image]

**Can you piece the shredded notes back together and figure out:**

- **Who likes who?**
- **Who am I?**

Comment: Given the title, there was a prime opportunity here to ask us to find "The New Order"

Comment: For those who don't get the comment above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvmupCCh6uM (I saw them playing this live a few months later in Helsinki.)

Comment: @LordFarquaad Exactly! You have to put the pieces into a new order.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the order is

> 1,8,5,7,4,2,3,6.

So,

> Harry Green has blue eyes, likes green hair. 
>  Olivia White likes Brown hair, has brown eyes. 
>  George Brown has black hair, likes grey eyes. 
>  Emily Black has green hair, likes black hair. 
>  Jack Grey likes black coffee, has white hair.

So, the love triangle is

> Harry likes Emily, who likes George.

You are probably

> Jack Grey, who by liking black coffee on his desk stays out of the madness of intra-office romance.

Comment: You could also switch 3 and 8, the "triangle features" are the same. I wonder if that means something or if it's just coincidence.

Comment: Good point @Christoph though I have it this way because I feel that grey is an acceptable eye colour whereas white is not.

Comment: you could also switch the 3rd, 4th and 5th with the 6th, 7th, 8th.   Good job!

Comment: Well done! And very quick too. I left it a while to give opportunity for some other answers.

Comment: I have one vote left... and now, I grant you $10$,$000$ reputation! Woo! :D

Comment: @Christoph There are two possible orders that give the same "right" answer. ROT13: (Gurer ner gjb "frgf" juvpu vapyhqr n ireo, n pbybhe, naq n abha. Fb ybat nf lbh trg rnpu frg evtug, vg qbrfa'g znggre juvpu jnl ebhaq gur frgf tb.)

Answer (score 5):

> Completely inspired by El-Guest's answer, but with a subtle (but I think correct) tweak

I actually think it is:

> Harry Green likes blue eyes, has green hair. 
> Olivia White has brown hair, likes brown eyes. 
>  
> George Brown likes black hair, has grey eyes. 
> Emily Black likes green hair, has black hair. 
> Jack Grey has black coffee, likes white hair.

Making the love triangle:

> George likes Emily, Emily likes Harry

You are:

> Jack because you **HAVE** black coffee in the picture (subtle difference from El-Guest's answer

Comment: He likes the black coffee _on his desk_, I believe I said. Great answer though!! :)

Comment: Yup! The subtle difference is ROT13(yvxrf if. unf).  I guess we'll find out the correct answer (either your answer or my answer inspired by you) :-)

Comment: Good luck to you! I think that we’re both referencing the fact that he has the object on the table though. That said, the actual non-pedantic difference in your solution (switching the order) does provide a second completely valid solution to the problem.

Comment: You too!  Yup, completely agree!

Comment: +1 for a great answer, not quite the order intended - who likes *white hair*?? But well done for spotting the coffee on the desk ;)

Comment: @Astralbee  Have you seen Daenerys Targaryen?

Answer (score 4):

oh, i came up with slightly different solution than @El-Guest:
order:

> 1,8,2,7,4,5,3,6

so

> Harry Green likes blue eyes, has green hair. 
>  Olivia White has Brown hair, likes brown eyes.  
>  George Brown likes black hair, has grey eyes.  
>  Emily Black likes green hair, has black hair.  
>  Jack Grey has black coffee, likes white hair.

So, the love triangle is

> George likes Emily but  Emily likes Harry

And

> you are still Jack Grey

Comment: Another +1 for a great attempt, not quite the order intended. Jack might appreciate an older woman, but *white hair*??

Answer (score 3):

> Judging by the coffee on your table, you're Jack :-)

Comment: Well done for spotting the coffee.

Answer (score 1):

> You are Jack White who found out that Harry Green likes Emily Black who likes George Grey.

Comment: Can you explain how you came to this conclusion, and use spoiler tags in your answer?